# Python class variables and methods visibility

Tags: python

I have a Python class (I cut some code to simplify):

```py
class c_DOT:
    color = 0

class c_TAIL:

    dot = c_DOT()

    tails = []

    def __init__(self) -> None:

        for i in range(10):
            self.tails.append(self.dot)
            self.tails[i].color = i
            print(self.tails[i].color)
            # here I see array with different values 0..9 - everything is okay.

    def test(self):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            print(self.tails[i].color)
        # here a I see only 9,9,..9
```

then:

```py
t = c_TAIL()

t.test()
```

As a result of the code above I got these lines:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
```

but why only 9,9,9??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the same object therefore every element in the array appear to have the same value as it is the reference to the same object.

Instead of `self.tails.append(self.dot)` you should do:

```
dot = c_DOT()
dot.color = i;
self.tails.append(dot).
```

or add a constructor to `c_DOT` class to set color upon object creation, so that you could do this: `self.tails.append(C_DOT(i))`.

Take a look at this. You will see that all array elements will always have the last index value on each iteration:

```
import pprint 

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

class c_DOT:
    color = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.color);

class c_TAIL:
    dot = c_DOT()
    tails = []

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        for i in range(10):
            self.tails.append(self.dot)
            self.tails[i].color = i
            pp.pprint(self.tails)

        print("---")
    
    def test(self):
        pp.pprint(self.tails);

obj = c_TAIL()
obj.test()
```

Answer (score 0):

you are appending same obj every time thats why when you are writing self.tails[i].color = i you are overwriting class variable by instance variable for your instance if you print(c_Dot.color) you will see your variable value is 0.

you can do this for your ideal result

```
class c_DOT:
    color = 0

class c_TAIL:

        # dot = c_DOT()

        tails = []

        def __init__(self) -> None:

            for i in range(10):
                self.dot = c_DOT() # for creating new obj every time 
                self.tails.append(self.dot)
                self.tails[i].color = i
                print(self.tails[i].color)

                #here I see array with different values 0..9 - everything is ok.

        def test(self):        
            for i in range(0, 10): 
                print(self.tails[i].color, "hello")
            #here a I see only 9,9,..9

    x = c_TAIL()
    x.test()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, is that you keep appending the same object `c_DOT`, and changing the color of that same object. This means that the color of `c_DOT` is the last color you set it to, thus `9`, and having made a list of references to the same `c_DOT` 9 times. What you would want to do is define a new `c_DOT` object to append to your `tails` list:

```py
class c_DOT:
    color = 0

class c_TAIL:
    
    tails = []

    def __init__(self) -> None:
      
        for i in range(10):
            dot = c_DOT()
            self.tails.append(dot)
            self.tails[i].color = i
            print(self.tails[i].color)
            #here I see array with different values 0..9 - everything is ok.
            
    def test(self):        
        for i in range(0, 10): 
            print(self.tails[i].color)
        #here a I see only 9,9,..9
        
t = c_TAIL()

t.test()
```

Answer (score 0):

When `__init__` is running and you are printing. The color value are changing in there instances hence you find output as 1,2,3.. so on. but they are all referencing to the same c_Dot instance see below image.

[image]

but when test function is running. the c_Dot instance has value 9 and all the list values are refrencing to that c_Dot instance. hence everytime you call any index the value 9 printed. see below image.

[image]